# prolonged impulse for GPIO input C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi, windows-iot-core-10

A digital acoustic sensor is connected to my raspberry.
Everytime it detects sound, it sets the input HIGH.
But it only appears to be active for a couple of milliseconds.
How can i prolong the signal within my program that it stays up for 500ms?
It is a functionality which I know from PLC contollers.

**Diagram**
Start: sensor input
Q: prolonged signal

[image: diagram]
 ,

Here my approach with the answer of Michael:
But still, it doesn't hold for Task.Delay. It goes off directly.

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        GPIOinit();
        Serial();
    }


    private void GPIOinit()
    {
        const int PIN_AKUSTIK = 19;

        GpioController gpio = GpioController.GetDefault();  //GPIO-Controller mit Default belegen
        pin_akustik = gpio.OpenPin(PIN_AKUSTIK);
    }


    public async void Serial() 
    {
      //serial configuration

        while (true)
        {
            //frequency of constant while loop 300ms
            Sensor_Akustik();
        }
    } 




    public void Sensor_Akustik()
    {
        pin_akustik.ValueChanged += Pin_ValueChanged;
        pin_akustik.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Input);

         status_akustik = pin_akustik.Read().ToString();
        textblock_DebugAkustik_live.Text = status_akustik;
        Messenger.Default.Send<string, Page_Akustik>(status_akustik);
    }

    private void Pin_ValueChanged(GpioPin sender, GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Edge == GpioPinEdge.RisingEdge)
        {
            sender.Write(GpioPinValue.High);

            Task.Delay(3000).Wait();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might refer to following code. You can try to update the latched output value for the pin if the pin is configured as an input.

```
    private void InitGPIO()
    {
        var gpio = GpioController.GetDefault();

        // Show an error if there is no GPIO controller
        if (gpio == null)
        {
            pin = null;
            GpioStatus.Text = "There is no GPIO controller on this device.";
            return;
        }

        pin = gpio.OpenPin(LED_PIN);
        pin.ValueChanged += Pin_ValueChanged;
        pin.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Input);

    }


    private void Pin_ValueChanged(GpioPin sender, GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if(args.Edge == GpioPinEdge.RisingEdge)
        {
            sender.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
            Task.Delay(500).Wait();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I edited my post with my approach. It doesn't do it yet. Am I missing something?

Comment: May i know the purpose of prolong the pulse is to filter out some signal noise? The [DebounceTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.gpio.gpiopin.debouncetimeout) property seems more suitable in this scenario.

Comment: The acoustic sensor detects clapping noises and sets the input HIGH. The impulse of a single clap is very short. I want to show a detected clap on the GUI. But like this it only pops up for a extremely short time, because the input is already back to LOW. When the input is HIGH, the popup message is supposed to stay for time x on the GUI regardless of the input state in that period.

Comment: I understand your purpose. Did you implement the clap display on GUI yourself? If that, in my opinion, you just need to prolong the GUI display instead of prolong the pulse.

Comment: Yes i made the GUI myself. How can I hold it on the GUI? My problem is the Serial( ). It calls Sensor_Akustik( ) every 300ms no matter what.

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet of making GUI? I'm not sure why you call the method Sensor_Akustik in a while loop.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I removed it from the while loop and separated it. Now i have a simple switch case to detect High. Different approach but it works for me.